# find the index of element being processed in a block, ruby

Tags: ruby

is there a way to know the index of the array element being processed by a block ?
I am trying to do something like this:

```
arr.any?{ |element| 
  # do some processing on the sub array  [ element.index + 1 , end]
}
```

of course I can try and accomplish what I want using a for loop, but I was wondering if I can use blocks to do it, just to have a more ruby-ish code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) and call it without block, so it returns `Enumerator`:

```
arr.each_with_index.any? do |el, index|
  # your condition using index here
end
```

Comment: Thank you !! ,Could you please add an example about getting back an Enumerator  ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi what do you mean by 'getting back an Enumerator'?

Comment: in your answer you said , 
call it without a block so it returns `Enumerator`" , I am not sure I understand what you mean by that. apologies I am new to ruby :)

Comment: oh oh, I see it now, never mind. 
thanks again for the answer, exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi yep. If you call `each_with_index` or related methods without passing a block, it returns [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerator.html) instance, on which you can perform other iterations.

Comment: Mhd, this answer is equivalent to: `enum = arr.each_with_index; enum.any? do |el, index|...end`. Perhaps that helps answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
array.each_with_index { |item, index|
  puts index
  puts item
}
```